# How to resolve these SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

Okay, so - I have 3 tables. 
Projects
Organizations
Contacts

I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve the relationships between them. 
Here are the business rules:

- One Organization can have many Employees
- One Organization can be hired to work on many projects
- One Employee can be part of One Organization
- One employee can be the contact on multiple projects
- One project can hire many organizations
- One Project can have many Employees (one contact for each organization)

Need to be able to assign contacts to both projects whilst being part of an organization
Need to be able to assign organizations to Projects
I've tried all I can think of to resolve the many to many relationships in there but can't find a way to make it all work... 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So you need an Employee table too, right?  Or is Contact supposed to be Employees?

Comment: What have you tried? Sometimes with simple schemas like this it's best if you draw it out, in an ERD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear to be fairly simple to map these relationships in the following way;

One Employee can be part of One Organization.

One Organization can have many Employees

```
This can be handled by having an OrganizationId on the Employee table.
```

One employee can be the contact on multiple projects

One project can hire many organizations

One Project can have many Employees (one contact for each organization)

One Organization can be hired to work on many projects

```
This seems to be handled by having a (some would call bridge table) ProjectResource table, which has a ProjectId and ContactId field. (This could also have OrganizationId, depending on how you are using the database, but to be more normalized, since it can be implied by the Contact, it is not needed)
```

Comment: This seems like it would work! I had previously only tried a bridge table between organizations and projects, didn't think of the employees table being there instead
Will put it all in and see how it behaves with a bit of test data and come back to say if it works or not. Thanks!

Comment: Question - with this bridge table, how do I go about updating a row? Should a contact leave their organization and a project needs to move that contact away or replace them 

Update projectID where contactID doesn't work as there are multiple instances of each within the table

Do I need a unique bridge Identifier?

Comment: One employee can only be on a given project once, so you can just do; SET ProjectId = y WHERE EmployeeId = x AND ProjectId = x

Answer (score 0):

As long as your relation between two particular table is many-to-many you may need to have a seperate table(also called bridge table in general) to represent that relation.

So you need these tables:

- Organization(has project foreign key, has Contact foreign key)
- Employee(has project foreign key)
- Project(has organization foreign key, has contact/employee foreign key[see contact])
- Contact(This table may or may not be necessary depending on whether a project can have multiple contacts or not. if it is unnecesarry you can replace all contact foreign keys with employee )
- Bridge Table between Organization and Project(has both organization and project foreign key)

I might have missed something but I think you got the point. You just need to draw an erd to determine all these relations clearly.